# Value obfuscation information at value level in RavenDB

Tags: encryption, obfuscation, ravendb

I am storing sensitive information within RavenDB relating to employee performance reviews.
As such, I need a simple first-line-of-defence against curious db admins, to prevent them from browsing the data.

I would class this as client-side encryption (although it need not be TNO) just really to obfuscate the data, however, in such a way that it obviously does not impact indexability.

**Notes:**

1. I am aware that indexed fields will remain unencrypted in Lucene.
2. I would *really* like to maintain document schema browsability if possible, so if someone were to use Raven Studio, they would see something like this (they can see the schema, not the data):

   `{
       WhatIThinkOfMyManager: 'jfjsd83hfdljdf983nofs==',
       AmIHappyWithMyPayLevel: false
   }`

Are there any facilitiesin Raven for this? And how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB 1.2 supports encryption of the data on disk (including in the indexes).
But an admin that has access to the data can see it in its decrypted form.

You might want to store the data inside RavenDB encrypted from your own code.